# How does gnome-maps get my current location?

Tags: gnome, geolocation

On my desktop computer (arch) and laptop (debian) I use gnome-maps. On both devices I use a VPN. (`iptables` firewall does not allow non-VPN traffic, no DNS leaks.)

On my desktop, the "current location" is the city where the VPN is, as expected.

On my laptop however, gnome-maps is able to get my actual location (VERY precisely, almost down to the foot).

How is that possible? What techniques are used? The laptop does not have GPS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`gnome-maps` uses `geoclue` which in turn uses the names/MACs of the wireless networks names and [Mozilla Location Services](https://location.services.mozilla.com/). That's how it gets your location. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_positioning_system) there is more information on wifi-based location technologies.

Dependencies might not allow for removal, but you can [disable `geoclue`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224487/uninstall-geoclue-from-debian).

Comment: So `geoclue` basically sends a list of nearby WiFi MAC's to the MLS API and gets a location in return, correct? That'd make sense, as my desktop PC has no WiFi.