# is there a command or a way to find how good or bad is the Geoclue Demo Agent?

Tags: debian, geolocation

In startup applications in Debian (as possibly other debian and ubuntu based distros.) there is a library called Geoclue Demo agent, the actual library with path is

```
/usr/libexec/geoclue-2.0/demos/agent
```

which is part of geoclue-2.0  https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/geoclue/geoclue/wikis/home .

The only question I know which has been asked so far is to remove the app/service. See the question [from](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224487/uninstall-geoclue-from-debian) unix.stackexchange.com .

I would find it more interesting if I could understand what it shows and how it shows it. The manpage written about man geoclue  isn't addressed for ordinary users.

Can somebody help me with that ? I am looking on lines something simple as `curl wttr.in/$location` and you get output of weather of that location. Something which is interactive and it probably is, just need to figure out how.

Answer (score 1):

On Stackoverflow I found question: [How do I get Geoclue Geolocation in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59677218/how-do-i-get-geoclue-geolocation-in-python-what-is-desktop-id-parameter)

After installing module to work with `GeoGlue`

```bsh
apt install gir1.2-geoclue-2.0
```

I created script **geolocation.py** in `python`

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import gi
gi.require_version('Geoclue', '2.0')
from gi.repository import Geoclue

clue = Geoclue.Simple.new_sync('something', Geoclue.AccuracyLevel.NEIGHBORHOOD, None)

location = clue.get_location()

latitude  = location.get_property('latitude')
longitude = location.get_property('longitude')

print('{},{}'.format(latitude, longitude))
```

which gives `latitude,longtiture` in `bash`

```bsh
python getlocation.py
```

and I can use it directly with `wttr.in`

```bsh
curl wttr.in/$(python getlocation.py)
```

If I set attribute `executable`

```bsh
chmod u+x geolocation.py
```

then I can even run it without `python` - it will use value from `shebang` (`#!/usr/bin/env python`)

I can even remove extension `.py` and keep name `geolocation` and then it will looks like

```bsh
curl wttr.in/$(getlocation)
```

(it has to be in `$( )` to execute it as separated process)

---

I can also use directly `python` to get value from server

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import gi
gi.require_version('Geoclue', '2.0')

from gi.repository import Geoclue

clue = Geoclue.Simple.new_sync('something', Geoclue.AccuracyLevel.NEIGHBORHOOD, None)
location = clue.get_location()

latitude  = location.get_property('latitude')
longitude = location.get_property('longitude')

#print('latitude :', latitude)
#print('longitude:', longitude)

import requests

url = 'https://wttr.in/{},{}'.format(latitude, longitude)

# to get it as HTML instead of TEXT (see PLAIN_TEXT_AGENTS in https://github.com/chubin/wttr.in/blob/master/lib/globals.py#L75)
#response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': ''}) #{'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

response = requests.get(url)

print(response.text)
```

If I would add `?format=j1` at the end of url

```
https://wttr.in/{},{}?format=j1
```

then I would get it as `JSON` which I could convert to `dictionary` in `python` and I would format data in different way.

---

Tested on `Linix Mint 20`, `Python 3.8`, `Python 2.7`

---

**By The Way:**

It seems `wttr.in` uses program [wego](https://github.com/schachmat/wego) which runs in terminal.

---

It seems `geoclue` uses different methods to recognize location but in my situation it probably used `IP` to recognize it - but my `Internet Provider` can change my `IP` every 24h and this `IP` can be used by users in different places so sometimes it gives incorrect locations. In this moment it gives me location almost 30km away from my place - and later `wttr.in` gives different weather.

---

Some web servers use [GeoIP from MaxMind](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/) to convert `IP` to location - but it has the same problem when user `IP` is changed every few hours. As I remeber it can be used by HTTP requests or you can download database with information and use it locally (but you have to update database from time to time)